# ProtractorHarnessEnvironment and matButton

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 9 with angular material 9 and flex layout.

I'm trying to make working some protractor tests with Angular Harness

The HTML I'm trying to test is the following

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="cvlBorderBottomRed">
  <mat-toolbar-row fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">

    <button id="cvl-brand" mat-button routerLink="">
      <img src="../../../../assets/icons/logo.svg" height="50" width="50" alt="My Company Logo"/>
      <span class="cvlTitle cvlFontWeight600">My Company <span class="cvlRed">Cool</span></span>
    </button>
    ...
    ...
  </mat-toolbar-row
<mat-toolbar>
```

My CSS is this

```
.cvlBorderBottomRed {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.cvlTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.cvlFontWeight600 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.cvlRed {
  color: red;
}
```

BUT, if I do the following, the button is not clicked

```
let harnessLoader = ProtractorHarnessEnvironment.loader();

const cvlBrand = await harnessLoader.getHarness<MatButtonHarness>(
    MatButtonHarness.with({selector: '#cvl-brand'}));

await cvlBrand.click();
```

Otherwise if I use the following code the button is correctly clicked

```
const cvlBrand = element(by.id('cvl-brand'));
await cvlBrand.click();
```

What's my fault?

Answer (score 0):

Updating from angular material 9.1.1 to 9.1.6 the problem is solved